# Add one object to multiple arrays and keep differences between each copy?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, instance

Basically, I want to create one object, and then add that object to a bunch of different arrays, and be sure that if one array changes the object's values, the other objects in other arrays don't change their values.

For example, say I declare a gun with 50 bullets stored in an integer:

```
Gun tommygun = new Gun(50);
```

I have two soldiers, each with a list of guns Guns, and add a tommygun to each one.

```
Soldier1.Guns.Add(tommygun);
Soldier2.Guns.Add(tommygun);
```

Soldier 1 shoots his gun:

```
Soldier1.Shoot(Soldier1.Guns[0]);
```

This decreases Soldier1's ammo by 1. It would now be 49. Does this also decrease Soldier2's gun's ammo? If so, how do I avoid that without creating a separate tommygun for every single soldier?

Comment: If you want to have Gun objects that maintain different information/state for each soldier, you should create separate Gun object instances for each soldier. That's what it is.

Comment: Why not give each solder his own gun: `Soldier1.Guns.Add(new Gun(50));
Soldier2.Guns.Add(new Gun(50));`?

Comment: `without creating a separate tommygun for every single soldier?` - does it not strike you as logical that each soldier has their own gun?

Comment: @Heinz my actual program has like 20 parameters for each gun and might have hundreds of soldiers, and if I need to adjust a gun I don't want to have to change the parameter 300 times (in every line where I declare a new gun).

Comment: @Merkava120: You can either create classes derived from `Gun` that have the intended parameters, or, if you really want to create duplicates of a Gun object, consider using `MemberwiseClone`, as proposed by Rufus L below.

Comment: Have all guns share the same `Parameters` object.

Comment: As a side note, you might consider moving your `Shoot` method to the `Gun` object, so that the code is a little less cumbersome: `Soldier1.Guns[0].Shoot()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to implement a `Clone` method on the `Gun` class. You can use [`MemeberwiseClone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.8) to create a shallow copy, and if needed you can then create new items for any reference type properties that `Gun` may have.

For example:

```
public class Gun
{
    public int MaxRounds { get; set; }
    public List<Bullet> Ammunition { get; set; } = new List<Bullet>();

    public Gun(int maxRounds)
    {
        MaxRounds = maxRounds;
    }

    public Gun Clone()
    {
        // Create a shallow copy of all the properties
        Gun newGun = MemberwiseClone() as Gun;

        // Because 'Bullet' is a reference type, we need to make a deep copy of 'Ammunition'
        newGun.Ammunition = Ammunition.Select(bullet => bullet.Clone()).ToList();

        return newGun;
    }
}

public class Bullet
{
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public int Range { get; set; }

    public Bullet Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone() as Bullet;
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Soldier1.Guns.Add(tommygun.Clone());
Soldier2.Guns.Add(tommygun.Clone());
```

Comment: This is great. What is the a => a.Clone() part doing, is that there because Ammunition is a list?

Comment: Yes, specifically because it's a list of a reference type. If it was just a `List<valueType>`, then we could do `newGun.Ammunition = Ammunition.ToList();` to create a new instance of the list. But because it contains reference types, we have to clone those as well (otherwise the `Bullet` objects inside each list point to the same thing).

Answer (score 5):

Create a separate instance of the tommy gun object, for each solider.

As objects are passed by reference, at the moment you are sharing one gun between two soldiers.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you are new in OOP

There are 2 ways that you can approach

1. Create new gun Instance
2. Create a [Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=netframework-4.8) of gun

Comment: Cloning seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: Technically, #2 is a subset of #1.

Comment: Yes, indeed. In some case you need to create a magical sword from my rusty sword, I though clone would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a deep copy. Otherwise, your Gun objects are aliases.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Gun g1 = new Gun(50);
            g1.addModification("Scope");
            Gun g2 = (Gun) g1.Clone();
            if (g1 != g2)
                Console.WriteLine("These objects are not aliases");
            Console.WriteLine(g1);
            Console.WriteLine(g2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Gun : ICloneable
    {
        int bullets;
        List<object> modifications;
        public Gun(int bullets)
        {
            this.bullets = bullets;
            modifications = new List<object>();
        }

        public void addModification(object o)
        {
            modifications.Add(o);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Bullets: " + bullets + " Modifications: " + modifications[0];
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            Gun clone = new Gun(this.bullets);
            foreach (object o in this.modifications)
                clone.modifications.Add(o);
            return clone;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically this doesn't perform a deep (or even shallow) copy, because if the instance of `Gun` that you're copying has any properties that were set outside of the constructor, they will not be copied from the original instance.

Comment: A deep copy simply copies each property of the class. In this case, the Gun class has a single property, bullets. Please enlighten me, what other types of copies are there besides deep and shallow?

Comment: Those are the only two types that I'm aware of. Shallow will copy all properties, where any reference type properties will point to the same object as the original, and a Deep will create new instances of reference types for those properties. But what I'm saying is that this example doesn't do either ***if the object has other properties that aren't set by the constructor***. But that's an implementation detail the OP can figure out - I wasn't criticizing your answer, just letting the OP know that this isn't demonstrating a deep copy (depending on the actual `Gun` class and how it's created).

Comment: But yes, in this specific example, the gun class has a single value-type property, so only a shallow copy would be needed. If, for example, the `Gun` class had a `Modifications` property that contains a list of objects, and we have `Gun tommyGun = new Gun(10); tommyGun.Modifications.Add(someModification); Gun tommyClone = (Gun)tommyGun.Clone();` In this case, the "clone" will not have the same modifications as the original.

Comment: A shallow copy and aliases are the same thing. I will update my answer to consider the Modifications property.

Comment: In most cases, its simpler to just create the object twice than try and perform a deep copy of the original. Use of the Builder pattern here would work too.

Comment: Consider an object with many properties. I think calling Clone once is easier but to each his own.

Comment: FYI, `clone.modifications.Add(o)` is performing a *shallow* copy of `o`